# ABD candidate who developed cognitive deficits. Current functioning level is "borderline" with average intelligence. Is there a way to navigate this?

Tags: advisor, teaching, job-search, health, all-but-dissertation

I'm a fourth year neurodivergent doctoral candidate who is also an instructor for this academic year (one year contract). I have had a tendency to make a fair amount of posts related to my struggles (for lack of a better term) and now I have an answer thanks to this neuropsychological assessment.

My intelligence measure was average. However, my processing speed was evaluated as "borderline." The only thing that equalized my overall average from being low average was that I got above average (82nd percentile) on. On the RBANS measure, my score was borderline sadly. I was two points away from being low average. The evaluator specifically note that it was much lower than expected given the intelligence measure.

I was rediagnosed with autism (level 1), ADHD-I, generalized anxiety disorder, major depressive disorder - moderate, and posttraumatic stress disorder (from my experience with my first advisor).

As much as I'm glad I have these diagnoses, I'm concerned about post Ph.D work now. I recently contacted vocational rehabilitation in my state to see what they can do for me. However, I'm worried because of how cognitively demanding and fast paced most post Ph.D jobs are based on what I know about them from my colleagues who've graduated from my program. I don't remember the metrics for productivity (I think they vary from workplace to workplace), but I could easily see myself falling through because I took too long to problem solve for my workplace and/or a client (if it's consulting).

I am conflicted about what I should do. Sadly, my university isn't partnered with the federal WRP program that could place me somewhere so I'm crossing my fingers that vocational rehabilitation can help someone who is about to get their Ph.D soon.

What could I do to navigate my situation? I'm going to tell my advisor this news tomorrow. As for the SLAC where I'm teaching, I already submitted an accommodation request and they're evaluating it with the Provost right now.

Comment: What did your career services offices suggest?

Comment: @Dawn I have a meeting with them a little over two weeks from now. I have vocational rehabilitation services in the loop in the meantime though

Comment: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/how-can-we-better-react-to-askers-who-are-having-a-mental-health-crisis

Comment: "Developed" or "recently diagnosed"?

Comment: @JonCuster I was recently diagnosed but it is based on cognitive issues that I've developed in this case.

Comment: Not really addressing the immediate question, but once you're in the workplace, don't fall into the trap of thinking that being a bit less productive (by some particular measure) than one's colleagues is some sort of moral failing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the right doctor.  It is extremely important that you get help from a qualified professional.  It is very probable it needs to be a specialist physician, or several kinds of medical specialists.

Actions your advisor or employer can take might help, but they will be nowhere near sufficient.

Comment: OP already mentioned seeing plenty of doctors...